# Prometheus Remote Endpoint that accepts data and forwards if network is available

Tags: prometheus

We use Prometheus to collect metrics data on devices such as Raspberry PIs. Does anyone know a remote endpoint (remote_write) that will accept all data and then forward *only* if a network connection is available. If not, the data should be stored and forwarded once the network is again availabe.

Does this feature exist already or can this be achieved with a different federation/remote_write setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would probably want to do is write something that accepts remote write from Prometheus, and then spools it locally to disk. It can then send it on in the form of a remote write request when there's network available.

Future versions of Prometheus may make this a bit easier to do.

Comment: We just discovered that the remote_write feature already has retries and backoff support. It might be good enough for our use case, but we're wondering what counts as a "failed attempt to write the data". Would it work if someone simply pulls the network cable for an unknown amount of time? Or is the metric data for the duration of the network outage lost?

Comment: The built in retries is only meant to cover brief network blips.